# How to set an array in json response goLang-gin

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have an array of stucts stored a variable my array.

Struct is

```
  type myStruct struct {
    id          int64   `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Name        string  `form:"name" db:"name" json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Status     string     `form:"status"  db:"status" json:"status" binding:"required"`
```

My array looks like this and is stored in a variable 'myArray'. This array is formed by iterating over a set of rows coming from database.

```
[{1 abc default} {2 xyz default}]
```

I am using gin as http server. How do I set this array into JSON reponse using c.JSON. Something like

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      name : 'abc' 
      status: 'default'
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      name : 'xyz' 
      status: 'default'
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

ok c.JSON(http.StatusOK, myArray) worked. But I cannot see the Id field in the response. Any reason why? Is it because of 'int64' dataType?

Comment: Because it is an unexported field (field starting with a lower case) and thus it can be marshalled.

Comment: yes just figured this out.Changing `id` to `Id` worked. Thanks!

Comment: how to set `Id` to `id` in the resulting json?